# pycharm crashes updating python paths

Tags: import, path, pycharm

Pycharm, and evidently the JetBrains IDE in general (due to a similar problem with IntelliJ), has difficulty with mundane operations, like opening a project. Specifically, aside from taking a good deal of time to reindex, it actually takes forever, as in never finishing, and freezing or slowing the entire computer's system in the process of "updating python paths".

On the recommendation of a fellow developer, and also related SO (Stack Overflow) post [Why is IntelliJ IDEA hanging on "Indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550292/why-is-intellij-idea-hanging-on-indexing) , I followed the advice given:

"In the File menu, select Invalidate Caches / Restart... and then click the Invalidate and Restart button."

And the caveat left in the comment:
"This worked for me but you have to be quick as if you can't get to the menu fast enough it freezes again."

There is also this from [JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207671405-stop-Indexing-please-?page=2)

Nothing really special in code, but there are a substantial number of imports that are part of the project, including many pip loaded libs. Also using a virtual environment, but owing to the above discussion, don't believe that has bearing on the difficulty. There are other project dependencies, but again, I don't think any are circular (I know Java IDE wouldn't allow), couldn't vouch for third-party libs. Have not experienced similar occurrence working in Eclipse, but unable to shift project work there presently. **Using Pycharm Pro 2018.2.7 on Mac OSX 10.13.4**

Just run of the mill import statements:

```
import python-logstash
```

One expects a project will open in an IDE without crashing one's computer. Having to open twice or thrice or more each time a project is closed (following the menu File, Invalidate caches/Restart...) is weird in paid software, for a known issue. And there is also always the race to run reopen before computer freezes. 
Doesn't happen on a very simple project. What is the trigger? Will JetBrains ever fix? Can one change code or imports to avoid?

Comment: It appears that a self referencing sym link was tripping the endless updating. Break the circular reference and the problem goes away.
It would still be useful to be able to
1) have some way to interrupt the process
2) have PyCharm detect there is a problem, a circular path
3) have PyCharm tell you what the problem is, circular path
4) all of the above, plus either disallow, or stop updating paths forever

Comment: It appears the self referencing sym link was NOT tripping the endless updating. Why then is PyCharm unable to open the project without a prolonged and debilitating condition during which the application is unusable for hours? I should try switching to Eclipse. I could also cut the project in half repeatedly to see if a certain piece or import triggers the hanging app.